# cv2.error (error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor')

Tags: python

Why can't I convert my images?

```
path = 'ImagesAttendance'
known_images = []
classNames = []
myList = os.listdir(path)
#print(myList)
for cls in myList:
    curImg = cv2.imread(f"{path}/{cls}")
    known_images.append(curImg)
    classNames.append(os.path.splitext(cls)[0])
print(classNames)

def find_encodings(images):
    encode_list = []
    for img in images:
        #img = face_recognition.load_image_file(images)
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        encode = face_recognition.face_encodings(img)[0]
        encode_list.append(encode)
    return encode_list

encodeListKnown = find_encodings(known_images)
```

The for loop is for looping through the images in my folder 'ImagesAttendance' and the function is for converting the list of images into RGB but it keeps on failing. The code is from a youtube tutorial about face recognition attendance system.
[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sz25xxF_AVE&ab_channel=Murtaza%27sWorkshop-RoboticsandAI)

Comment: please provide us with the error messages or the results of the code to better help you fix the problem.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\nero1\VScode\face_recognition\attendance.py", line 25, in <module>
    encode_known_list = find_encoding(images)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\nero1\VScode\face_recognition\attendance.py", line 20, in find_encoding
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.7.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'